# An attribute is a variable?

Tags: python, class, object

Suppose I have an object with an attribute, say:

```
class Monkey:
    def __init__(self, size):
        self.size = size
monkey = Monkey(4)
```

Then we have an attribute `monkey.size`. Is this a variable associated with the object 4?

Comment: Yes, you can think of attributes as variables who's namespaces are instances/classes

Comment: I honestly don't understand what you are asking, though. Is this a question about terminology?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it create an instance of `Monkey`. And property `size` of that instance has value `4`.
To be more clear, I recommend you to read: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_classes_objects.htm